# Unable to open URLs using python webdriver for selenium 2.0

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, python-2.7

I am new to both Python as well as Selenium and and still in the learning phase. I have been trying to launch both IE8 as well as Firefox using the new Python Webdriver for Selenium with the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Ie() 
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

In case of Firefox, it launches the broswer with my home page while it does not even launch the IE8 browser.

In either case I can see this exception in my command prompt window.

```
File "C:\Documents and Settings\user.name\My Documents\seleniumScripts\test1.py", 
line   > 8, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Ie()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.7.0
-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 58, in __init_

desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.7.0-
py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 61, in __i
it__self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.7.0
- py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 98, in sta
t_session
'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.7.0-
py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 144, in excute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.7.0-  
py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 100, 
in check_response
raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-    //W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
 r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error Message</TITLE>\r\n<META http-equiv=Content-Type 
 content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\r\n<ST
 LE id=L_default_1>A {\r\n\tFONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #005a80; FONT-       FAMILY: tahoma\r\n}\r\nA:hover {\r\
 \tFONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #0d3372; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma\r\n}\r\nTD
  {\r\n\tFONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY
  tahoma\r\n}\r\nTD.titleBorder {\r\n\tBORDER-RIGHT: #955319 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: 
 #955319 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 8px
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 0px 
 solid; COLOR: #955319; BORDER-BOT
 OM: #955319 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma; HEIGHT: 35px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d2b87a; 
 TEXT-ALIGN: left\r\n}\r\nTD.titleB

 rder_x {\r\n\tBORDER-RIGHT: #955319 0px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid; PADDING-     LEFT: 8px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FON
 -SIZE: 12pt; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 1px solid; COLOR: #978c79; 
 BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid;
 ONT-FAMILY: tahoma; HEIGHT: 35px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d2b87a; TEXT-ALIGN: left\r\n}
 \r\n.TitleDescription {\r\n\tFONT-WEI
 HT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma\r\n} 
\r\nSPAN.explain      
 {\r\n\tFONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE
  10pt; COLOR: #934225\r\n}\r\nSPAN.TryThings {\r\n\tFONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 
10pt; 
 COLOR: #934225\r\n}\r\n.TryLi
 t {\r\n\tMARGIN-TOP: 5px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: 
 tahoma\r\n}\r\n.X {\r\n\tBORD
 R-RIGHT: #955319 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-     
 SIZE: 12pt; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 1
 x solid; COLOR: #7b3807; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: verdana;      
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d1c2b4\r\n}\r\n.adm
 nList {\r\n\tMARGIN-TOP: 2px\r\n}\r\n</STYLE>\r\n<META content="MSHTML 6.00.2800.1170" 
 name=GENERATOR></HEAD>\r\n<BODY
  gColor=#f3f3ed>\r\n<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">\r\n  <TBODY>\r\n  
  <TR>\r\n    <TD class=titleborder
x width=30>\r\n      <TABLE height=25 cellSpacing=2 cellPadding=0 width=25    
bgColor=black>\r\n        <TBODY>\r\n
<TR>\r\n          <TD class=x vAlign=center align=middle>X</TD>\r\n            
</TR>\r\n        </TBODY>\r\n      </TABLE>\
\n    </TD>\r\n    <TD class=titleBorder id=L_default_2>Network Access Message:<SPAN    
class=TitleDescription> The page cannot be displayed</SPAN> </TD>\r\n  </TR>\r\n         
</TBODY>\r\n</TABLE>\r\n\r\n<TABLE id=spacer>\r\n  <TBODY>\r\n  <TR>\r\n
<TD height=10></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>\r\n<TABLE width=400>\r\n  <TBODY>\r\n  
<TR>\r\n    
<TD noWrap width=25></TD\r\n    <TD width=400><SPAN class=explain><ID     
id=L_default_3><B>Explanation:</B></ID></SPAN><ID id=L_default_4> There i
 a problem with the page you are trying to reach and it cannot be displayed.     
</ID><BR><BR>\r\n    <B><SPAN class=tryThi
 gs><ID id=L_default_5><B>Try the following:</B></ID></SPAN></B> \r\n      <UL     
class=TryList>\r\n        <LI id=L_defaul
_6><B>Refresh page:</B> Search for the page again by clicking the Refresh button. The 
timeout may have occurred due to
nternet congestion.\r\n<LI id=L_default_7><B>Check spelling:</B> Check that you typed 
the Web page address correctly. The address may have been mistyped.\r\n<LI 
id=L_default_8><B>Access from a link:</B> If 
there is a link to the page you a
e looking for, try accessing the page from that link.\r\n\r\n      </UL>\r\n<ID     
id=L_default_9>If you are still not abl
 to view the requested page, try contacting your administrator or Helpdesk.</ID>     
<BR><BR>\r\n    </TD>\r\n  </TR>\r\n

/TBODY>\r\n</TABLE>\r\n\r\n<TABLE id=spacer><TBODY><TR><TD 
height=15></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>\r\n\r\n<TABLE width=400

\r\n  <TBODY>\r\n  <TR>\r\n    <TD noWrap width=25></TD>\r\n    <TD width=400 
id=L_default_10><B>Technical Information
for support personnel)</B> \r\n      <UL class=adminList>\r\n        <LI     
id=L_default_11>Error Code: 407 Proxy Authenti

ation Required. The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to 
the Web Proxy filter is denied.
(12209)\r\n<LI id=L_default_12>IP Address: 11.1.11.111\r\n<LI id=L_default_13>Date: 
9/30/2011 3:23:59 PM [GMT]\r\n<LI i

=L_default_14>Server: servername.com\r\n<LI id=L_default_15>Source: proxy\r\n\r\n      
</UL>\r\n    </TD>

r\n  </TR>\r\n  </TBODY>\r\n</TABLE>\r\n\r\n</BODY>\r\n</HTML>\r\n\r\n'
```

ANy help would be really appeciated as I am completely stuck and kind of desperate now.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running IE8 on windows 7?

Comment: Its IE8 on Windows XP Profession SP3

Comment: Have you tried running the example to open python.org through a console? I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and getting a similar error when running unit tests but works through console